# labels on imagesc plot: why they are duplicated?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I try to make a labelled plot using `imagesc`, with labels on the tick-axes, but I get two times as many labels as needed. What I am doing wrong? I tried both R2009B and R2017A.

[image: output from my code]

Below is my code:

```
test_data = rand(5,5);
[RHO,PVAL_spearman] = corr(test_data,'Type','Spearman');
figure;
imagesc(RHO);
labelNames = {'item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'};
set(gca,'XTickLabel',labelNames);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',labelNames);
```

Comment: You have specified five tick labels, but you have not done anything with the ticks themselves. If you just use `imagesc(test_data)`, you'll see that it actually places 11 ticks along both axes (from 0.5 to 5.5 with an interval of 0.5). If you replace your last two commands by `set(gca,'Xtick',1:5,'XTickLabel',labelNames);` it should look fine.

Comment: If the answer below helped you, please consider accepting it. There's no obligation to do so, but it gives both you and the answerer (me) a bit of rep, and the community at large will know you no longer need help.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the default number of ticks on plots is 11, so you simply need to change the amount of ticks using the `set(gca,'XTick',N)` property:

```
N = 5;
test_data = rand(N);
[RHO,PVAL_spearman] = corr(test_data,'Type','Spearman');
figure;
imagesc(RHO);
labelNames = {'item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'};
set(gca,'XTick',1:N);
set(gca,'YTick',1:N);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',labelNames);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',labelNames);
```

[image]

When specifying less than 11 label names MATLAB simply starts again at the first, until it has placed 11 labels, and when you provide more than 11, MATLAB ignores the labels beyond place 11.